# Changing Specific Cylinder Radius or Diameter in Blender 2.9

Tags: mesh

I'm just getting started using Blender and have found tutorials on changing the radius or diameter by mouse, but I want my work to be precise so I much rather prefer putting in the actual numbers. Again, I'm looking for a way to change the radius or diameter of a cylinder using the 2.91 version of Blender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the tools parameters that appear at the bottom left of the viewport (or press <kbd>F9</kbd> to have them appear on a floating window).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've been trying to access that menu by hitting F9 but all it shows is the words "Toggle Editmode"? Think there's a setting or something someplace that doesn't allow me to get to that.

Comment: That window (and the one I the bottom left corner) is only available during the creation of the object. Once you've created the object and done any kind of transformation (move, rotate or scale, or selected any other object) the creation parameters will not be available anymore

Answer (score 2):

After the mesh is created, you can use the sidebar to change its dimensions.
Display the sidebar via the menu view -> check Sidebar. Then in the sidebar change the relevant Dimensions.[image: Sidebar activation and dimension change]