# How do I enter numbers to enter size dimensions?

Tags: dimensions

I have a cylinder on the Plater.  Where do I enter a size dimension numbers?

[image]

A search has many hits with advanced info.  I'm seeking basic info.

I have viewed [Changing Specific Cylinder Radius or Diameter in Blender 2.9](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206253/changing-specific-cylinder-radius-or-diameter-in-blender-2-9). I'm using Blender 3.0.

The Transform does not provide dimensions either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press N, then on tab "Item" you can enter dimensions.

[image]

Instead of pressing N you can click with the mouse on that little arrow pointing to the left.

[image]

Comment: N works.  Is there an icon for the mouse?

Comment: yes, i updated my answer